# Can I deploy to ARM from nexus?

Tags: maven, mule, nexus

Do you know if it is possible that I deploy an application from nexus to my Anypoint Runtime Manager (ARM) in order to automate this in my jenkins pipeline

I am deploying to nexus, but now I want to pull from it

Comment: If I correctly understand your question: You only want to consume those artifacts which you have deployed beforehand ? If yes than of course...

Comment: yes this is what I want, but I should automate this in my pipeline

Comment: So in the end it's only a question how to automate the deployment part which means downloading the artifacts and deploy them onto the target environment...

Comment: yes , I should download the artifacts from nexus and deploy them to mule's ARM